# Python variables and files

Tags: python, file, variables

Is there any way I can make so that I can treat a file as a variable?
As an example when the function save from PIL Image module is called: `Image.save("foo.jpg")` i would like all the data *not to save on the hard disk* but to be introduced in a variable `a` so that when `a.read()` is called, it should return what the content of the file would be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [BytesIO](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) class to save a PIL Image to a byte stream.

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> im = Image.open('ball.png')
>>> from io import BytesIO
>>> buffer = BytesIO()
>>> im.save(buffer, format='png')
>>> buffer.getvalue()
'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\ ...
```

It's probably worth reading through the whole [io module page](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/io.html), it's pretty short, lots of good info, contains StringIO as ch3ka pointed out.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked, but one more question, what is the purpose of 'im.write'?

Comment: That was me forgetting the proper Image class method to save for a bit, I've just removed :)

Answer (score 7):

sure, take a look in the `StringIO` module. It provides a file-like interface for strings.

http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html

```
StringIO - File-like objects that read from or write to a string buffer.
```